# Make my MDI application topmost of other applications?

Tags: windows, mfc, window, mdi

I want to make my `MDI MFC` `application` topmost of `all other applications' windows` running on windows OS. So I can make a screen shot of `one view` within my application.
But functions like `SetWindowPos(&CWnd::wndTopMost, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);` or `SetFocus()` (called in my `view class`) doesn't work at all.
Whenever `another application's window` is on the top of mine's and I make a `screenshot`, it will save a picture of the `window` on top of mine.

**So how to make `my application's windows`(specifically `the view window)` on top of `other applications' windows`?**

Comment: Use bold or italic markups (\* or \*\*) instead of the code (\`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to make my MDI MFC application topmost of all other applications' windows.

This is simply not possible. If your application could do that, then so could the other applications. Only one could win, and there's no reason why your application could be more special than the others.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SetWindowPos(&CWnd::wndTopMost, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW|SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE);
```

or:

```
BringWindowToTop( );
```

Comment: Not work, I think I should activate my window (or "set focus")first.

Comment: @RubbyMath - The SetWindowPos API call works ! But you must call it in the CFrame class as only application main windows can be brought to the top-most, not any child views nor child windows.

Comment: there a small trick how to steal a focus in the latest versions of Windows. See this article (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1724/Some-handy-dialog-box-tricks-tips-and-workarounds) (search on the page for term "How to steal focus")